# Flutter : Access data from Map (key, value)

Tags: flutter

I need to access the data from key, value pair.

```
CashfreePGSDK.doPayment(inputParams)
        .then((value) => value?.forEach((key, value) {
              print("$key : $value");
          
              //Do something with the result
            }));
```

Currently, i am getting

```
I/flutter (30088): txStatus : SUCCESS
I/flutter (30088): orderAmount : 951.00
I/flutter (30088): paymentMode : CREDIT_CARD
I/flutter (30088): orderId : 61
I/flutter (30088): txTime : 2021-10-18 13:28:59
I/flutter (30088): signature : cMFtQPuqyibAN+=
I/flutter (30088): txMsg : Transaction Successful
I/flutter (30088): type : CashFreeResponse
I/flutter (30088): referenceId : 1121337
```

I need to keep the data in variable like i have a variable Status. So, i want to put Success in the Status. Similarly for rest of the data.

Can someone advise me on this.

Comment: You have different variables for each of them?

Comment: Yes, i have created the variable for all these to keep the values there instead of printing.

Comment: One way can be to check for the key and store in the variable accordingly. But it is a long method.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect you need it

```
Column(
         ...CashfreePGSDK.doPayment(inputParams)
        .then((value) => value
             .asMap().map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, Card(
                    title: value["title"],)))
                 .values.toList(
                growable: true,
             ),
          ),
```

Comment: i didn't understand it. You haven't put any variable.

Comment: it's not obligatory, if you want put it change `.map((key, value) => MapEntry` to `.map((index, value) { final anyVar = value[index]; return MapEntry(...`

Answer (score 0):

```
  CashfreePGSDK.doPayment(inputParams).then((value) {
  print(value);
  print(value!['txStatus']);
  var ans=value!['txStatus'];
});
```

}

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.